# Why is symmetric group action needed for symmetric spectra?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I know that Boardman spectra aren't supposed to have an on-the-nose commutative
smash product, and symmetric spectra -- which look like essentially the same
thing, except the spaces $X_n$ have to come with an action of the symmetric group
-- do. Essentially, I'm trying to understand why adding this simple condition is
the right thing to do.

If $X,Y$ are symmetric spectra, then $(X\wedge Y)_n$ is defined as the coequalizer of

$$ \alpha_X,\alpha_Y:\bigvee_{p+1+q=n}\Sigma^+_n\wedge_{\Sigma_p\times
\Sigma_1\times \Sigma_q}X_p\wedge S^1\wedge Y_q\rightrightarrows
\bigvee_{p+q=n}\Sigma^+_n\wedge_{\Sigma_p\times \Sigma_q}X_p\wedge Y_q$$
where $\alpha_X$ is induced by $X_p\wedge S^1\wedge Y_q\overset{\sigma_p\otimes
1}\to X_{p+1}\wedge Y_q$ (where $\sigma_p$ is the structure map) and $\alpha_Y$ is
induced by $X_p\wedge S^1\wedge Y_q\overset{\text{twist}}\to X_p\wedge Y_q
\wedge S^1\overset{1\otimes\sigma_q}\to X_p\wedge Y_{q+1}\to X_p\wedge Y_{1+q}$
where the last map uses the $\Sigma_{q+1}$-action.

My question is why the $\Sigma$-action is necessary: you can try to make a
parallel construction, where you omit the group actions and say $(X \wedge Y)_n$
is the coequalizer of 
$$ \alpha_X,\alpha_Y:\bigvee_{p+1+q=n}X_p\wedge S^1\wedge Y_q\rightrightarrows
\bigvee_{p+q=n}X_p\wedge Y_q$$
where $\alpha_X$ is induced by $X_p\wedge S^1\wedge Y_q\overset{\sigma_p\otimes
1}\to X_{p+1}\wedge Y_q$ and $\alpha_Y$ is
induced by

- $X_p\wedge S^1\wedge Y_q\overset{1\otimes\sigma_q}\to X_p\wedge Y_{q+1}$
  (where I'm assuming the existence of structure maps $S^1\wedge X_n\to X_n$ as
  well as $X_n\wedge S^1\to X_n$ with some compatibility properties)
  or just
- $X_p\wedge S^1\wedge Y_q\overset{\text{twist}}\to X_p\wedge Y_q
  \wedge S^1\overset{1\otimes\sigma_q}\to X_p\wedge Y_{q+1}$.

I feel like I'm sort of missing the point of this construction; can someone
fill me in? Thanks!

Comment: We know that connective spectra are spaces with an action of the E_infty operad, and you can explicitly write down deloopings. I wonder if you can reinvent this formula by writing down the formula for the deloopings of a smash product of E_infty spaces? The symmetric group appears because it acts on the spaces of the operad